# How to create a UserControl which accepts adding child elements in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

### Goal:

I want to achieve something similar to the `GroupBox` control.

I want to have some design and controls wrapping around a child element which I specify in XAML:

*Current code:*

```xml
<GroupBox Header="Filter">
    <local:Filterview></local:Filterview>
</GroupBox>
```

*Goal:*

```xml
<objectViews:ContractableGroupBox Header="TEST">
    <local:Filterview></local:Filterview>
</objectViews:ContractableGroupBox>
```

### Current Situation / Issue:

My custom "groupbox" works as far as adding it to the Form and setting the header but it does not work properly when adding the child element `Filterview`.

Working (But no content):

```xml
<objectViews:ContractableGroupBox Header="TEST">
</objectViews:ContractableGroupBox>
```

[image: Contractable group box without content shows header.]

Bugs out (content is there but wrapping not):

```xml
<objectViews:ContractableGroupBox Header="TEST">
    <local:Filterview></local:Filterview>
</objectViews:ContractableGroupBox>
```

[image: Contractable group box with content does not show header.]

### Code Behind:

This is the XAML of `ContractableGroupBox`:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SoundStudio.Views.ObjectViews.ContractableGroupBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoundStudio.Views.ObjectViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF303030" Background="#FF646464" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" >
            <Expander x:Name="ExpanderContent" Header="{Binding Header}" IsExpanded="True">
                
            </Expander>
        </Border>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note, I want to specify the child element in the parent `UserControl`, but it should be displayed as if in the `Expander` node such as:

```xml
<Expander x:Name="ExpanderContent" Header="{Binding Header}" IsExpanded="True">
    <local:Filterview></local:Filterview>    
</Expander>
```

This is the current `ContractableGroupBox.cs`

```cs
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SoundStudio.Views.ObjectViews
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ContractableGroupBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ContractableGroupBox : UserControl
    {
        public ContractableGroupBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        public string Header { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see ist that the following XAML **overrides** the content of your `UserControl`, which includes the `Grid` and the `Expander` itself and that is why the header is seemingly lost.

```
<objectViews:ContractableGroupBox Header="TEST">
    <local:Filterview></local:Filterview>
</objectViews:ContractableGroupBox>
```

As a general advise, **do not** ever set the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` to itself, this will break data context inheritance and is bad practice. Regarding your issue, you should make `Header` a dependency property to enable data binding and add another dependency property for the  content of the expander, e.g. `ExpanderContent` (`Content` already exists on `UserControl`).

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(ExpanderContent))]
public partial class ContractableGroupBox : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Header), typeof(string), typeof(ContractableGroupBox));


   public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpanderContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(ExpanderContent), typeof(object), typeof(ContractableGroupBox));


   public ContractableGroupBox()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   public string Header
   {
      get => (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
      set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
   }

   public object ExpanderContent
   {
      get => GetValue(ExpanderContentProperty);
      set => SetValue(ExpanderContentProperty, value);
   }
}
```

The `ContentProperty` attribute at the top will make sure that anything you put inside this user control in XAML like below will be assigned to the `ExpanderContent` property instead of the `Content` property that the `UserControl` type already provides. If you do not do this, you have to assign your content manually to `ExpanderContent`, otherwise the actual content of the `UserControl` itself (your `Grid`, `Expander`, etc. will be overridden.

```
<objectViews:ContractableGroupBox Header="TEST">
    <local:Filterview></local:Filterview>
</objectViews:ContractableGroupBox>
```

You have to change your user control XAML bindings using `RelativeSource` and `AncestorType`, so that they resolve the dependency properties `Header` and `ExpanderContent` on your control. Notice, that I renamed the `Expander` to `Expander` to avoid a naming collision with the dependency property `ExpanderContent`. Now that the bindings use the dependency properties, there is even no need for setting the `DataContext`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SoundStudio.Views.ObjectViews.ContractableGroupBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoundStudio.Views.ObjectViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
   <Grid>
      <Border BorderBrush="#FF303030" Background="#FF646464" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" >
         <Expander x:Name="Expander"
                   IsExpanded="True"
                   Header="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                   Content="{Binding ExpanderContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
      </Border>  
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

However, if the only thing that you want to add to the `Expander` is a `Border` around it, then you do not have to create a separate `UserControl`. You could just create a custom control template for `Expander` by copying its default template and add a `Border` there.

Comment: thank you for the extensive explanations. This is one of the best answers I have received yet!
Also thank you for the advice with setting self on the datacontext. I am quite new to wpf data binding coming from winforms and in this case mainly relied on reading questions and tutorials on other places.